# Firing event when scroll bar reaches the bottom of panel

Tags: c#, winforms, events, scrollbar, panel

I have a winform application where I want a event to be fired when the scrollbar reaches the bottom of panel.

I tried this:

```
private void Panel1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
//some operation
}
```

But it is firing event everytime I scroll the Scrollbar not when I reach the end.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: similar; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682312/how-to-detect-if-winforms-panel-has-scrolled-to-the-end

Comment: Have you tried to use the **NewValue** property of the **ScrollEventArgs**?
You can retrieve the value of the Scrollbar with **e.NewValue**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [`ScrollEventArgs.NewValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrolleventargs.newvalue(v=vs.100).aspx) Property. Like this:

```
private void Panel1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue == panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum - panel1.VerticalScroll.LargeChange + 1)
    {
       if(e.NewValue != e.OldValue) // Checking when the scrollbar is at bottom and user clicks/scrolls the scrollbar      
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Test"); // Some operation
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll)
{
    VScrollProperties vs = panel2.VerticalScroll;
    if (e.NewValue == vs.Maximum - vs.LargeChange+1)
    {
        //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
        {
            if (e.NewValue + panel1.Width > panel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum)
                MessageBox.Show("End of Horizontal Scroll");
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.NewValue + panel1.Height > panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum)
                MessageBox.Show("End of Vertical Scroll");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void panel1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
            {
                if(panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value == panel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum)
                {
                    //end
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (panel1.VerticalScroll.Value == panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum)
                {
                    //end
                }
            }
        }
```